# MS PowerPoint JavaScript API - insert SVG as shape?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I'm using the `Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync()` method and `Office.CoercionType.XmlSvg` to insert complex objects into slides, which works quite well!

The only caveat seems to be that you need to right click and "Convert to Shape" before they can be edited inside PowerPoint. Is there some way to insert SVG objects as a Shape or to effectively automate the "Convert to Shape" step using the JavaScript API?

Comment: What kind of edits do you need that are not working for SVG objects? As far as I can see we can insert SVG's using setSelectedDataAsync and then using the UI we can rotate/resize/fill and change bunch of properties. If you can share us your scenario about what you need from shapes that is not supported in SVGs that would be great.

Comment: Sure! My use case is to insert the contents of an entire PowerPoint slide - along the lines of inserting a template - and then to be able to edit it normally. The template slide has been previously converted to SVG. This works great, but to be able to edit the components of the inserted template/slide/object as if it had been created manually in PowerPoint, you first need to convert the object to a Shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, thanks for the additional explanation, unfortunately currently PowerPoint OfficeJS Api is very thin, although it is being actively worked on, there is currently no other API to do the "Convert to Shape" or insert a shape yet.

I don't know your requirements, however, may I recommend you a newly released API which allows you to insert a slide from a PPTX file? Instead of converting to SVG, you can possibly insert directly. This is currently available in Public Preview which you can find information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.presentation?view=powerpoint-js-preview#insertSlidesFromBase64_base64File__options_

Preview API list can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/powerpoint-preview-apis

Here are some sample code to insert slides from existing files:

```
    await PowerPoint.run(async function(context) {
      context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64( base64EncodedPptxFileAsString );
      context.sync();
    });

    await PowerPoint.run(async function (context) {
      context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64( base64EncodedPptxFileAsString,
        {
          formatting: "UseDestinationTheme",
          targetSlideId: "257#",
          sourceSlideIds: ["257#3396654126", "258#"]
        });
      context.sync();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Onur! The only caveat with insertSlidesFromBase64 is that, unless I'm mistaken, it can't insert/merge elements into an existing slide. Still, I'm really glad to hear that the API is still being developed further.

Comment: That is correct joelby, however inserting shapes+images/pictures to existing slides are on the list of things to come soon.